# Azure Cloud Service Virtual Directory Issue

Tags: azure, virtual-directory, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to add virtual directory in WebRole1 of my could service using following directive in csdf file...

```
<Site name="Web">
    <VirtualDirectory name="aspnet_client" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\crazureresource\aspnet_client" />
      <VirtualDirectory name="Downloads" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\crazureresource\Downloads" />        
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

The development machine directory structure is...

```
..\CR1\CR1\ProjectFiles
..\CR1\crazureresource\aspnet_client
..\CR1\crazureresource\Downloads
```

The azure webrole1 directory structure is...

```
siteroot\0\website-deployed-files
siteroot\crazureresource\aspnet_client
siteroot\crazureresource\Downloads
```

The package gets published successfully; instance is also updated but WebRole's status is either 'Busy' or 'Restarting'. The website is not deployed on the webrole. If I shorten the path of virtual directory to

```
> ..\..\..\aspnet_clients and ..\..\..\Downloads
```

It works (the deployment); but the contents are modified on azure cloud service. In place of these physical folders a new folder by the name of 1 and 2 are created. Inside these two replacement folders, config files are placed by system - the original files are replaced. While at the same time in IIS, a valid link shows for virtual directory.

I am not able to access the resources from virtual directory due to this!

Answer (score 0):

For Azure this is the valid directory structure

```
siteroot\0\website-deployed-files
siteroot\1\                         ----name it as aspnet_client
siteroot\2\                         ----name it as Downloads
```

and the contents will be availble like below urls

```
www.exapmple.com   --- default (website-deployed-files)
www.exapmple.com/aspnet_client    --contents of (aspnet_client) 
www.exapmple.com/Downloads        --contents of Downloads
```

you can update you local directroy  structure to match.

for the path in csdef file

```
physicalDirectory="..\..\..\crazureresource\Downloads"
```

This is the path from **/bin** directory of **Azure project** to  the Other projects **Downloads.csproj directory**.
 Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417679/cannot-find-the-physical-directory-for-virtual-path-in-windows-azure-project-sd) for updating the Path properly in your csdef file

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the result is same. The two virtual directories I am trying to add is not a separate project rather simple directory.